# Can not acess the JSON data inside the object. property

Tags: javascript, json, object, console.log, lit-element

I am currently working on LitElement project. I added JSON data in to the category.items property using this code,

```
fetchItems(category) {   
    if (!category || category.items) {
      return;
    }

    this.getResource({
      url: 'data/' + category.name + '.json',
      onLoad(e) {
        category.items= JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
      },

    });
}

 getResource(rq) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', rq.onLoad.bind(this));
    xhr.open('GET', rq.url);
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

Then I tried to get those data in another component, But I cannot access the Items property.

The code I use to get the data,

```
handleCategoriesyChanged(e) {
    this.categories = e.detail.categories.value; 
    if(this.location!=undefined){
        for(let i=0; i<this.categories.length ;i++){
            if(this.location.params[0]==this.categories[i].name){
                this.item = this.categories[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(this.item);
        console.log(this.item.items);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.item, null ,2));
        console.log(this.item.items);
    }
```

this is the console.log output get in chrome.
[image]

When I called the object Its show the items property, But i can not access it. So , I tried with the JSON.stringify method and that time not show the items property.I went through the similar question like this in this site,But I can not identify what went wrong and why this happen in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mutating your `this.item` and add field `items` somewhere after your logs. This is a reason why there is no key `items` in your JSON.stringify.

`console.log(this.item);` log a reference to `this.items` and output will be changed when you change object by the reference.

Try to execute this code and expand first console.log output to see what I'm talking about.

```
var object = {};
console.log(object);
console.log(object.a);
object.a = 'first key';
console.log(object);
```